# how to fix assertion failed exception in delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, c++builder-xe5

How to fix assertion error in delphi XE5 RAD studio?
In my project i have a sqlconnection which connects to fire bird database.
when i set connected property to true, the compiler show an error which is.

```
"Assertion failed: this => hdbc==, file..\..\ib\sqld\ibconn.cc, line83".
```

after press OK button the IDE getting close suddenly. 
I am using XE5 as developemnt IDE.
i cannot understand what is this exception why it cause.
can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: You should probably take this up with Embarcadero. From the error, it looks like what was supposed to be a valid database connection handle wasn't at a crucial point in the database driver layer.